# d3 v4: Stacked histogram with some series below x axis?

Tags: d3.js

Say I have some data (e.g. book loans and book returns). I want to plot this in a histogram, but I also want it to be 'stacked' in that book loans should be positive (above the x axis) while book returns should be negative (below the x axis). I've not been able to find any documentation on this, and the closest example is [this one](https://bl.ocks.org/sbrudz/8ac4f4102f787d0fcea5), but it uses the old v3 of d3 (which has changed a LOT regarding the stack api), and it also doesn't have negative stacks. The key thing here is that originally the book return data point isn't negative (in fact, it can't be, since the histogram api generates the bins), so I can't simply force that one series to appear below the axis in that way.

edit: after struggling with histograms + bins for a while, I finally got an example going at [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWENOq?editors=0010). In my case, I'd like for the 'FixedRemaining' series to appear below the axis while the 'Remaining' series stays above. The data is pretty simple, and the code for drawing the rects is taken mostly from [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208). In particular, I suspect this line would have to change:

```
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
```

since it currently just sets the height to be above the axis. I know the domain would also have to be modified to take into account the below-axis part.

Comment: can you provide a little of your dataset or code?

Comment: @torresomar Added a codepen to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by mbostock in this block here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/b5935342c6d21928111928401e2c8608